# TypeError: Cannot read property 'isEnabled' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to make an application that will disconnect and connect Wi-Fi and get a status about the network. I am using react-native-android-wifi but when calling any function I get an error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'isEnabled' of undefined".
Made from this docs and https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-wifi
error screen :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/kat8L.jpg

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Modal,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableHighlight,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  PermissionsAndroid
} from 'react-native';

import { wifi } from 'react-native-android-wifi';

// Props = {};
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isWifiNetworkEnabled: null,
      ssid: null,
      pass: null,
      ssidExist: null,
      currentSSID: null,
      currentBSSID: null,
      wifiList: null,
      modalVisible: false,
      status: null,
      level: null,
      ip: null,
    };

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(wifi);
    this.askForUserPermissions();
  }

  async askForUserPermissions() {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        {
          'title': 'Wifi networks',
          'message': 'We need your permission in order to find wifi networks'
        }
      )
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log("Thank you for your permission! :)");
      } else {
        console.log("You will not able to retrieve wifi available networks list");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err)
    }
  }

  serviceCheckOnPress() {
    wifi.isEnabled(
      (isEnabled) => {
        this.setState({ isWifiNetworkEnabled: isEnabled });
        console.log(isEnabled);
      });
  }

  serviceSetEnableOnPress(enabled) {
    wifi.setEnabled(enabled)
  }

  connectOnPress() {
    wifi.findAndConnect(this.state.ssid, this.state.pass, (found) => {
      this.setState({ ssidExist: found });
    });
  }

  disconnectOnPress() {
    wifi.disconnect();
  }

  getSSIDOnPress() {
    wifi.getSSID((ssid) => {
      this.setState({ currentSSID: ssid });
    });
  }

  getBSSIDOnPress() {
    wifi.getBSSID((bssid) => {
      this.setState({ currentBSSID: bssid });
    });
  }

  getWifiNetworksOnPress() {
    wifi.loadWifiList((wifiStringList) => {
      console.log(wifiStringList);
      var wifiArray = JSON.parse(wifiStringList);
      this.setState({
        wifiList: wifiArray,
        modalVisible: true
      });
    },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  connectionStatusOnPress() {
    wifi.connectionStatus((isConnected) => {
      this.setState({ status: isConnected });
    });
  }

  levelOnPress() {
    wifi.getCurrentSignalStrength((level) => {
      this.setState({ level: level });
    });
  }

  ipOnPress() {
    wifi.getIP((ip) => {
      this.setState({ ip: ip });
    });
  }


  renderModal() {
    var wifiListComponents = [];
    for (w in this.state.wifiList) {
      wifiListComponents.push(
        <View key={w} style={styles.instructionsContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.instructionsTitle}>{this.state.wifiList[w].SSID}</Text>
          <Text>BSSID: {this.state.wifiList[w].BSSID}</Text>
          <Text>Capabilities: {this.state.wifiList[w].capabilities}</Text>
          <Text>Frequency: {this.state.wifiList[w].frequency}</Text>
          <Text>Level: {this.state.wifiList[w].level}</Text>
          <Text>Timestamp: {this.state.wifiList[w].timestamp}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
    return wifiListComponents;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>React Native Android Wifi Example App</Text>
          <View style={styles.instructionsContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.instructionsTitle}>Check wifi service status</Text>
            <View style={styles.row}>
              <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this.serviceCheckOnPress.bind(this)}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Check</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
              <Text style={styles.answer}>{this.state.isWifiNetworkEnabled == null ? "" : this.state.isWifiNetworkEnabled ? "Wifi service enabled :)" : "Wifi service disabled :("}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.instructionsContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.instructionsTitle}>Enable/Disable wifi network</Text>
            <View style={styles.row}>
              <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this.serviceSetEnableOnPress.bind(this, true)}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Enable</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
              <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this.serviceSetEnableOnPress.bind(this, false)}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Disable</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.instructionsContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.instructionsTitle}>Sign device into a specific network:</Text>
            <Text style={styles.instructions}>SSID</Text>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.textInput}
              underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
              onChangeText={(event) => this.state.ssid = event}
              value={this.state.ssid}
              placeholder={'ssid'} />
            <Text style={styles.instructions}>Password</Text>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.textInput}
              secureTextEntry={true}
              underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
              onChangeText={(event) => this.state.pass = event}
              value={this.state.pass}
              placeholder={'password'} />
            <View style={styles.row}>
              <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this.connectOnPress.bind(this)}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Connect</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
              <Text style={styles.answer}>{this.state.ssidExist == null ? "" : this.state.ssidExist ? "Network in range :)" : "Network out of range :("}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.instructionsContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.instructionsTitle}>Disconnect current wifi network</Text>
            <View style={styles.row}>
              <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this.disconnectOnPress.bind(this)}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Disconnect</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.instructionsContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.instructionsTitle}>Current SSID</Text>
            <View style={styles.row}>
              <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this.getSSIDOnPress.bind(this)}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Get SSID</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
              <Text style={styles.answer}>{this.state.currentSSID + ""}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.instructionsContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.instructionsTitle}>Current BSSID</Text>
            <View style={styles.row}>
              <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this.getBSSIDOnPress.bind(this)}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Get BSSID</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
              <Text style={styles.answer}>{this.state.currentBSSID + ""}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.instructionsContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.instructionsTitle}>Get all wifi networks in range</Text>
            <TouchableHighlight style={styles.bigButton} onPress={this.getWifiNetworksOnPress.bind(this)}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Available WIFI Networks</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.instructionsContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.instructionsTitle}>Connection status</Text>
            <View style={styles.row}>
              <TouchableHighlight style={styles.bigButton} onPress={this.connectionStatusOnPress.bind(this)}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Get connection status</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
              <Text style={styles.answer}>{this.state.status == null ? "" : this.state.status ? "You're connected :)" : "You're not connected :("}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.instructionsContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.instructionsTitle}>Get current wifi signal strength</Text>
            <View style={styles.row}>
              <TouchableHighlight style={styles.bigButton} onPress={this.levelOnPress.bind(this)}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Get signal strength</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
              <Text style={styles.answer}>{this.state.level == null ? "" : this.state.level}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.instructionsContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.instructionsTitle}>Get current IP</Text>
            <View style={styles.row}>
              <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this.ipOnPress.bind(this)}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Get IP</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
              <Text style={styles.answer}>{this.state.ip == null ? "" : this.state.ip}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
        <Modal
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => { }}>
          <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={() => this.setState({ modalVisible: false })}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Close</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
          <ScrollView>
            {this.renderModal()}
          </ScrollView>
        </Modal>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Just making sure, was the package installed before running the app?

Comment: You have a typo. Change `import { wifi } from 'react-native-android-wifi';` to `import wifi from 'react-native-android-wifi';`

Comment: i did but it didn't help i still get the same error

Comment: Then the package has not been installed?

Comment: the package has been installed

Comment: What does `console.log(wifi);` in the constructor output?

Comment: console.log(wifi) i get "null"

Comment: Did you install [the native dependencies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-wifi#install-the-native-dependencies)?

Comment: i get error when calling dependency

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/HburntQ

Comment: That's a warning not an error.

Comment: figured I added the dependency, but the problem is still there

Comment: Then I think you're missing information for us to help.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Something else is likely to be incorrect. Something not in the question. The two/three main issues we thought could be the cause were not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have imported `wifi` in a working way, Correct your import statement as below,

```
import wifi from 'react-native-android-wifi';
```

and not,

```
import { wifi } from 'react-native-android-wifi';
```

Comment: Please flag as a typo.

Comment: i did but it didn't help
i still get the same error

Comment: Please make sure you are using the updated version of react-native-android-wifi and following install as mentioned here https://github.com/devstepbcn/react-native-android-wifi/blob/master/docs/link-manually.md